# application hangs when closing a listening port

Tags: c#, multithreading, com0com

I'm using com0com to create a part of virtual ports comA/comB, typing the input to comA from hyperterminal and listening on comB in a wpf application. When I run the following code (by triggering `Connect`), the application successfully connects and is able to get the data from comA, but hangs when I do `Disconnect`.

```
    public void Connect()
    {
        readPort = new SerialPort("COMB");
        readPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
        readPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        readPort.Open();

        readThread = new Thread(Read);
        readRunning = true;
        readThread.Start();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("connected");
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        if (!readRunning)
        {
            readPort.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            readRunning = false;
            readThread.Join();
            readPort.Close();
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("disconnected");
    }

    public void Read()
    {
        while (readRunning)
        {
            try
            {
                int readData = 0;
                readData = readPort.ReadByte();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("message: " + readData.ToString());
            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried changing the Read function to a write by using

```
byte[] writeData = { 1, 2, 3 };
readPort.Write(writeData, 0, 3);
```

instead of `port.readbyte`, and it starts working perfectly when disconnecting. Does anyone know if there is anything different about `readbyte` that could have caused the freeze? Or is it possibly related to com0com?

Comment: How did you declare readRunning?

Comment: In `Disconnect`, try closing the port before joining to the reader thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checking back, in case anyone runs into the same issue, I found an alternative way overriding `SerialPort.DataReceived` like this:

```
    public override void OnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        byte[] buf = new byte[sp.BytesToRead];
        sp.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        receivedDataDel(buf);
    }
```

Comment: For posterity any chance you could include the code?

Comment: Excellent. However, it's not entirely clear to me how this relates to the previous code. Is this a new handler that you've added and attached somewhere or would this have been referenced in your original code, but not in a bit you've included in the original post? Also, you can accept your own post as the answer.

Comment: I added to the code `port.DataReceived += OnDataReceived`, instead of using `port.readbyte`